# How to get a name of enclosing type in static context?

Tags: c#

Say you have:

```
class Foo
{
   static string f = nameof(Foo);
}
```

This works but I don't like having explicit type name in `nameof`. In instance context I could use `this.GetType().Name`, but how to get the type name in static context (without explicitly referring to type as above)?

Comment: But even then `GetType` gives you the *runtime* type, which if inheritance is in play isn't necessarily the same as the *static* type where the code resides. At least we *have* `nameof` now, which refactoring tools can understand. Previously we had to just use a string...

Comment: No, you can't..

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, true, but it would suffice for my needs (most of the time I use sealed types).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Foo
{
    static string f = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
}
```

Comment: This is a static field of an object. It's not a method itself so you will not get the type of `Foo` here.

Comment: @Sefe: Did you try? `f` should be set to "Foo" in the sample code above.

Comment: @Sefe - initializers do end up inside a method, just not one of your own writing if you don't supply one. The class will have a static constructor and the initializer code ends up in there.